# Get all transactions prior to 3 minutes ago with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a transaction table, with a primary key of transcationId, a string transactionType, and a datetime stamp in the style of

```
2017-03-09 20:49:13.870
```

I want to select all transactions of transactionType 'CreditCard' that took place prior to 3 minutes ago. I have

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TRANSACTION 
WHERE  transactionType ='CreditCard' 
AND    transactionDate < dateadd(minute, -3, GETDATE())
```

Is that how to use the dateadd function in this case?

Comment: *"Is that how to use the dateadd function"* Did it give you the correct results? Then yes it is...

Comment: Its part of a system that is very difficult to test data on locally.

Comment: It's correct, @Amanda_Panda. You could load some test data and check... 
like here: http://rextester.com/KTOG3014

Comment: If you need to test on live data, then you have some much larger problems to deal with first...

Comment: Here is one thing good with prefixing - you never use reserved words as identifires....

Comment: Unless you are looking for the odd case (which I have encountered) where if it is 09:15:15 you are looking for transactions entered before 09:12:00, then yes, you are using it correctly.

Comment: Remember you can test it pretty easily:  SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -3, GETDATE())

Comment: Yep, sorry I was being dense earlier. It should be easy to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to use `dateadd()` for 10 minutes ago if your `transactionDate` is based on server time and is a `datetime` datatype.

```
select *
from [transaction]
where transactionType = 'CreditCard' 
  and transactionDate < dateadd(minute, -3, getdate())
```

If you wanted to truncate to the minute, you would use:

```
select *
from [transaction]
where transactionType = 'CreditCard' 
  and transactionDate < dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, getdate() )-3, 0)
```

To avoid any implicit conversions between `datetime` and `datetime2(7)`:

If `transactionDate` is local time and a `datetime` datatype, then you would use `getdate()`.

If `transactionDate` is local time and a `datetime2` datatype, then you would use `sysdatetime()`.

If `transactionDate` is UTC time (Coordinated Universal Time) and a `datetime` datatype, then you would use `getutcdate()`.

If `transactionDate` is UTC time (Coordinated Universal Time) and a `datetime2` datatype, then you would use `sysutcdatetime()`.

The differences between datatype and function results are explained here: [**`sysdatetime()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: You really should have edited your first answer, not posted a new one.